# Using logical operation on sorted array (keep sorted array after logical operation)

Tags: matlab, boolean, logical-operators

**Idea**

I have the following problem. In order to increase my code speed I am trying to write most of my script as logical operation rather then as for-loops or the like.

**Problem**

I have a sorted array and I want to keep it sorted as I need it sorted as input for the next function. In order to do so I used the following code:

```
target_level=sortrows(target_level,-9);
for i= 1:length(target_level);
   ii=find(BML(:,1)==target_level(i,1));
   targets(1,i)=ii;
end
```

So I want to find the index of the matrix BML for every element of     `"target_level(:,1)"`, while keeping the sorting. In order to loose the for-loop and write this as a logical operation I tried:

```
targets=ismember(BML(:,1),target_level(:,1));
targets=find(targets(:,1)==1);
```

It comes up with the same results, the only problem is that I loose the sorting which I applied on a variable that I dont really want to keep.

**Question**

Is there a way to keep the sorting while using logical operations?

Comment: You should avoid using the `length` function, the `size` and `numel` functions do the same thing but are far less risky.

Comment: In which way risky ? I use them quite a lot, would be good to know what the risk is :)

Comment: `length` outputs the number of elements in the largest direction. So if you change the size of your array, `length` can refer to the size of either the first or second dimension, and you generally don't want such a variability in your loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the indexes while keeping the sorting you can simply use the second output of `ismember`:

```
[~, targets] = ismember(BML(:,1),target_level(:,1));
```

Best,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To come to the outcome I wanted you have to change BML and target_level in your answer to `[~, targets] = ismember(target_level(:,1),BML(:,1));` but it provided great help. Thanks!